# Como R calcula o seguinte código?

Tags: r

```
2 + 2 %>% sqrt()
```

Porque o resultado não é 2, mas sim 3.4142?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `R` o operador `%>%` é chamado de pipe, ele vai usar o valor mais a esquerda para passar para a função, veja o que seria equivalente

```
library(magrittr)

print(2 + 2 %>% sqrt())

print(sqrt(2)+2)
```

Resultado de cada print:

```
[1] 3.414214
[1] 3.414214
```

vc deve estar imaginando que ele iria passar `2+2` = 4 para o sqrt, mas não é isso que acontece, isso seria verdade se 2+2 estivesse entre parenteses `(2+2)`

```
print((2 + 2) %>% sqrt()) == 2
```

Answer (score 6):

Isso ocorre porque o R segue as convenções da matemática. Primeiro é feita a potenciação e sua operação inversa, depois multiplicação e sua inversa e, por fim, adição e sua inversa. Dessa forma, `2 + 2 %>% sqrt()` significa criar a expressão `2 + sqrt(2)`.

Para obter o resultado desejado, é necessário informar explicitamente que a adição possui prioridade em relação à potenciação (afinal, tirar a raiz quadrada é equivalente a elevar um número à potência 1/2) nesse caso. Para fazer isso, execute `(2 + 2) %>% sqrt()`